# What does the `overwrite` parameter in Pandas DataFrame.update() function do?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) documentation but I do not understand what the `overwrite` option actually does to the `update` process. I tested with a few cases but in each whether or not I set `overwrite` to `True` or `False` makes no difference. Can someone give an example where it does make a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that when `overwrite` is set to false, it will only fill in missing values in the `DataFrame` that `update` was called on.

Based on the example from the link you supplied (using the default value `overwrite=True`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2,3], 'B': [400, None, 600]})
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [4, 5, 6],  'C': [7, 8, 9]})
df.update(new_df)
```

yields:

```
   A    B
0  1  4.0
1  2  5.0
2  3  6.0
```

whereas `df.update(new_df, overwrite=False)` yields:

```
   A      B
0  1  400.0
1  2    5.0
2  3  600.0
```