# Replace values in one dataframe with values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and I am trying to replace all values of 0 from the first dataframe with certain values from the second dataframe.

The first dataframe looks like this:

| Region | Country | Product | Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Africa | South Africa | ABC | 500 | 1200 |
| Africa | South Africa | DEF | 200 | 400 |
| Africa | South Africa | XYZ | 0 | 0 |
| Africa | Nigeria | DEF | 150 | 450 |
| Africa | Nigeria | XYZ | 200 | 750 |
| Asia | Japan | XYZ | 100 | 500 |
| Asia | Japan | ABC | 200 | 500 |
| Asia | Japan | DEF | 0 | 0 |
| Asia | India | XYZ | 250 | 600 |
| Asia | India | ABC | 100 | 400 |
| Asia | India | DEF | 40 | 220 |

It contains quantities and total price for each type of product for each  country. Some country and product combinations have values of 0.

The second dataframe looks like this:

| Region | Product | Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Africa | ABC | 375 | 825 |
| Africa | DEF | 125 | 250 |
| Africa | XYZ | 110 | 300 |
| Asia | XYZ | 200 | 500 |
| Asia | ABC | 200 | 500 |
| Asia | DEF | 120 | 300 |

The second dataframe contains the region averages for quantity and price across each product.

The task is to replace all 0 values in dataframe 1 with the averages for that region and product from dataframe 2.

For example, the 0 values for South Africa for product XYZ in dataframe 1 should be replaced with the values for product XYZ for Africa in dataframe 2. The other values for South Africa should stay the same and so on.

Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: Do zeroes always come in pairs?

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar Yes they do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) after replacing `0` with `np.nan` and setting a common `index` between the two dataframes.

Be wary of two things:

1. Use [`overwrite=False`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48696195/what-does-the-overwrite-parameter-in-pandas-dataframe-update-function-do) to only fill the null values
2. `update` modifies [`inplace`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-does-inplace-mean-in-pandas/#:%7E:text=Inplace%20is%20an%20argument%20used,are%20using%20fillna()%20methods.)

```
common_index = ['Region','Product']
df_indexed = df.replace(0,np.nan).set_index(common_index)
df2_indexed = df2.set_index(common_index)

df_indexed.update(df2_indexed,overwrite=False)
```

---

```
print(df_indexed.reset_index())

    Region Product       Country  Quantity   Price
0   Africa     ABC  South Africa     500.0  1200.0
1   Africa     DEF  South Africa     200.0   400.0
2   Africa     XYZ  South Africa     110.0   300.0
3   Africa     DEF       Nigeria     150.0   450.0
4   Africa     XYZ       Nigeria     200.0   750.0
5     Asia     XYZ         Japan     100.0   500.0
6     Asia     ABC         Japan     200.0   500.0
7     Asia     DEF         Japan     120.0   300.0
8     Asia     XYZ         India     250.0   600.0
9     Asia     ABC         India     100.0   400.0
10    Asia     DEF         India      40.0   220.0
```

Answer (score 2):

First, get all average values merged into the first df, a joining is suffice.

```py
df1_merged = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['Region', 'Product'], suffixes=('','_Average'))
```

we get `df1_merged` as

|  | Region | Country | Product | Quantity | Price | Quantity_Average | Price_Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Africa | South Africa | ABC | 500 | 1200 | 375 | 825 |
| 1 | Africa | South Africa | DEF | 200 | 400 | 125 | 250 |
| 2 | Africa | South Africa | XYZ | 0 | 0 | 110 | 300 |
| 3 | Africa | Nigeria | DEF | 150 | 450 | 125 | 250 |
| 4 | Africa | Nigeria | XYZ | 200 | 750 | 110 | 300 |
| 5 | Asia | Japan | XYZ | 100 | 500 | 200 | 500 |
| 6 | Asia | Japan | ABC | 200 | 500 | 200 | 500 |
| 7 | Asia | Japan | DEF | 0 | 0 | 120 | 300 |
| 8 | Asia | India | XYZ | 250 | 600 | 200 | 500 |
| 9 | Asia | India | ABC | 100 | 400 | 200 | 500 |
| 10 | Asia | India | DEF | 40 | 220 | 120 | 300 |

Then we can fillin these zero with `Average` columns with conditional `loc`

```py
df1_merged.loc[df1_merged['Quantity'] == 0, 'Quantity'] = \
df1_merged['Quantity_Average']

df1_merged.loc[df1_merged['Price'] == 0, 'Price'] = \
df1_merged['Price_Average']
```

now we get `df1_merged` as

|  | Region | Country | Product | Quantity | Price | Quantity_Average | Price_Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Africa | South Africa | ABC | 500 | 1200 | 375 | 825 |
| 1 | Africa | South Africa | DEF | 200 | 400 | 125 | 250 |
| 2 | Africa | South Africa | XYZ | 110 | 300 | 110 | 300 |
| 3 | Africa | Nigeria | DEF | 150 | 450 | 125 | 250 |
| 4 | Africa | Nigeria | XYZ | 200 | 750 | 110 | 300 |
| 5 | Asia | Japan | XYZ | 100 | 500 | 200 | 500 |
| 6 | Asia | Japan | ABC | 200 | 500 | 200 | 500 |
| 7 | Asia | Japan | DEF | 120 | 300 | 120 | 300 |
| 8 | Asia | India | XYZ | 250 | 600 | 200 | 500 |
| 9 | Asia | India | ABC | 100 | 400 | 200 | 500 |
| 10 | Asia | India | DEF | 40 | 220 | 120 | 300 |

Finally, drop unneeded columns with

```py
df1_merged = df1_merged.drop(['Quantity_Average', 'Price_Average'], axis=1)
```

and we get

|  | Region | Country | Product | Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Africa | South Africa | ABC | 500 | 1200 |
| 1 | Africa | South Africa | DEF | 200 | 400 |
| 2 | Africa | South Africa | XYZ | 110 | 300 |
| 3 | Africa | Nigeria | DEF | 150 | 450 |
| 4 | Africa | Nigeria | XYZ | 200 | 750 |
| 5 | Asia | Japan | XYZ | 100 | 500 |
| 6 | Asia | Japan | ABC | 200 | 500 |
| 7 | Asia | Japan | DEF | 120 | 300 |
| 8 | Asia | India | XYZ | 250 | 600 |
| 9 | Asia | India | ABC | 100 | 400 |
| 10 | Asia | India | DEF | 40 | 220 |